# i can´t use ng serve angular cli problems with my version of node

Tags: angular-cli, node-modules, serve

when i try to use ng serve i recived this messagge:

As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
shortly after.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".

You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command.

this is my version of angular cli, node and npm:

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.11.4
os: win32 x64

thanks for help

Comment: The angular CLI is on version 1.4.5 now. You should consider moving to a non-beta version at some point. Something that might help you make the change: [Angular CLI migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update).

Comment: thanks a lot , this works for me